# Dictionary which allows specific searches

Tags: discussion, online-resources, resource-request

I am searching for an English and/or American English dictionary which enables me to search, for example

> Nouns which begins/ends/includes the chunk 'exa'

Does anyone know such an online dictionary with this capabilities?

Comment: There aren't any dictionaries with this capability. But you might try COCA, as mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: @IͶΔ - Actually, let me provide a counter**exa**mple: [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com), which allows for searches such as the O.P. is requesting.

Comment: Odd, I had posted a comment with a link to the resources thread and OneLook before the question was moved, and it's disappeared. OneLook is linked in the resources thread btw.

Comment: Oh, close as a dupe of resources Q? @Colleen

Comment: I don't know about closing it as a duplicate, but let's link the [Resources for learning English](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/735/) thread to it.

Comment: @Colleed - Odd indeed. Your comment is still on the original question. For some reason, the comment didn't migrate with the question.

Answer (score 7):

The dictionary site [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/) has search features like those. You can use wildcard symbols for letters, and limit the search to certain parts of speech as well.

[Here's an example](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*exa*&posfilter=cn&scwo=1&sswo=1), using the parameters you put forth in your question (i.e., nouns containing `exa`).

For what it's worth, 36 words were found:

> (1) adnexa
>   (2) alexandrite
>   (3) annexation
>   (4) counterexample
>   (5) dexamethasone
>   (6) exacerbation
>   (7) exacta
>   (8) exaction
>   (9) exactitude
>   (10) exactness
>   (11) exaggeration
>   (12) exaltation
>   (13) exam
>   (14) examen
>   (15) examination
>   (16) examinee
>   (17) examiner
>   (18) example
>   (19) exanthem
>   (20) exanthema
>   (21) exarch
>   (22) exarchate
>   (23) exasperation
>   (24) hexachlorophene
>   (25) hexagon
>   (26) hexagram
>   (27) hexahedron
>   (28) hexameter
>   (29) hexane
>   (30) indexation
>   (31) inexactitude
>   (32) inexactness
>   (33) methotrexate
>   (34) reexamination
>   (35) sexagenarian
>   (36) vexation

Answer (score 5):

I can recommend you the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/). A *Corpus* is a set of texts written in a certain language. You can find many of them online and they are a very good source of research for collocations, phrasing and word choice as native speakers would do. It's not a dictionary, though. I'm afraid you can find the words there and then, if you don't know their meaning, get a dictionary to help you.

You can search for words which contain chunks like this:

```
*exa
```

For words which end in "exa"

```
exa*
```

For words which start with "exa"

```
*exa*
```

For words which contain "exa"

Comment: I might amend to suggest the [corpus.byu.edu](http://corpus.byu.edu/) as a whole, which offers several different corpora in addition to the COCA. It has become even more useful now that Oxford has discontinued the simple search functions on the BNC.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers have pointed out [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) and [OneLook](http://onelook.com/?w=&ls=a), both of which are excellent resources.  I'd like to add a few more:

- The excellent [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/search/?q=*exa*) lets you search for `*exa*`, but you'll notice it sometimes takes a bit longer for the page to load.  That's because it's not just searching headwords, but definitions as well!  So for example, *physical* shows up because the definition contains the word ***exa**mination*.
- If you click 'advanced search' on Ben Zimmer's [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/), you can search for words beginning with *exa*, and you can limit it to nouns, too.  This has some other neat functions, like letting you search for words that rhyme with your search term, so depending on what you want, this could be very useful!
- You can also search [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=exa*&title=Special%3ASearch) for words beginning with *exa* by searching for `exa*`, but the site currently doesn't have a function to search for words ending in *exa*.

If you're a computer person, you can download word lists and use `grep` on your own computer.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers give more user-friendly options, I often use the [Visca.com Regex Dictionary](https://www.visca.com/regexdict/) which allows more powerful matching (e.g., `^[aeiou].*exa$` for a word starting with a vowel that ends in `exa` — it only matches "adnexa") and also supports part of speech matching. For letters that appear anywhere in a word, it would just be `exa`.

See also this [regex quick start guide](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html).